# Display Full Table without scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I want to display 12 column table without scrollbar in smaller screens. Table should shrink to the device width. How can i achieve  it ?

Comment: With that demanding attitude and no attempts to solve the issue yourself, I don't think you're ever gonna achieve it :) .

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't, or how to make, this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be aware of various units of measurement in CSS such as `px`, `em`, `rem`, `pt` etc.

A more recent innovation in CSS units of measurement (since around 2011) are viewport units:

- `vw` - 1% of the width of the browser viewport
- `vh` - 1% of the height of the browser viewport
- `vmax` - whichever is the greater, `vw` or `vh`
- `vmin` - whichever is the lesser, `vw` or `vh`

Consequently if you style your table with:

```
table {
width: 95vw;
max-width: 95vw;
}
```

your table will always be 95% of the width of the browser viewport, no matter how wide or how narrow that viewport happens to be.